# how to append all matching Ids to its array in coldfusion/cfml?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfml

I am trying to append all the emp ids to its corresponding array as shown in the image below. Is there a way to make it something like that with my code below. Here is my sql statement that I am trying to mimic that sql statement to an api as shown below. so, is it possibe? thanks for the help. **Basically, I am only retrieving one empID, however I want to display all the EMPIDS**

Basically, I want to do this with my code below:

```
<cfscript>
       myArray=[1,2,3,4,5];
       ArrayAppend(myArray,[8,9],"false"); // merge=false
       writedump(myArray) //adds the new array as a single element
</cfscript>
```

Comment: We have already touched on `checkDefined` function. Can we get rid of that?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: On `myAPIOutput`, do you want an struct? or an array? I am also wondering if you have a PHP background because their terminology is different.

Comment: I want it to be struct. And I do have some PHP background but kind of rusty on it

Comment: Basically, right now I am getting one object from the list, I want to get 1,2,3 of the matching department_id (to get all the matching eids not  only one object for each dept ids

Comment: When you write `arrayLen(myAPIOutput[item.departmentNbr])` , what do you think that means and more importantly, what do you want it have as a value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219003/discussion-between-scott-and-james-a-mohler).

Comment: After looking back at your original question, I'm not sure I understand again. You say you want to retrieve 1 ID, which is what we showed you with the `filter()`, but then you say you want to display all IDs. What's the difference between retrieving 1 and displaying all in your expected results? This sounds like it may be one piece of a bigger problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: What does your incoming JSON look like, what do you expect to get back out of it, and how are you planning to use that result?

Comment: hey Shawn see the discussions room

Comment: @Scott Sorry, I did. I was in that discussion. I just had a couple of other questions, but if your problem's solved, good deal. Just please make sure to update the question and an answer so that future readers can get the help they're looking for.

Comment: Hey @Shawn this not quite answer my problem. However, how can I return all the departmentNbr and not filtered ones. Like I dont want to hardcode the 7777 the filtered way is good but I also want to show all the departmentNbr and then filtered to its proper departmentNbr as we have already

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure I understand your question. You don't want to filter the departmentNbr, and return all numbers, but then filter them. What are you expecting to be returned from your API?

Comment: Well, I am trying to return all the `departmentNbr` from the api not only the first object from the api. For example: if I have a departmentNbr 7777, I want to return all the departmentNbr 7777 not only the first object that has department 7777. Does that make sense. Right, Now in the code that James answered kind works  but thats when I hardcode "7777" inside `item.keyExists("departmentNbr")`

Comment: @Shawn can we chat inside the discussion? I want to further understand the solution and need help on some of my problems in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the chat, it looks like what was needed was a `filter()`

```
private array function my_api_second() {
    return jsonData.filter(
       function(item) { return item.keyExists("departmentNbr"); }
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I did it something different by using `ArrayFilter` function (see updated code)

Comment: but i have a question how can I return all the `departmentNbr` and not filtered ones. Like I dont want to hardcode the `7777` the filtered way is good but I also want to show all the `departmentNbr` and then filtered to its proper departmentNbr as we have already

Comment: Array filter is just more typing, but it is the same thing. Look at the chat, we cover how to filter by a specific departmentNumber. Not to mention there is a link to trycf.com. Last but not least, You should make a new question. This is a new concern that you have.

Comment: Thank you, James!

Comment: basically, I need to do in my function that should save it as a struct then you should be able to access the save variable

Comment: like I created a test struct that is a variable that saves the data my function generates, is it possible ?